# Is Cod fish halal or not?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I want to go to some place where Cod fish will be served for dinner. Is it halal or not?

Does cod fish have scale which would make it halal to eat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is halal to eat [Cod fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cod) and [cod liver oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cod_liver_oil).

And they [do have scales](http://animalquestions.org/fish/cod/do-cod-have-scales/), which from a Shiite perspective make it halal to eat.

Sources:

- [List of scale fish](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/46/2081/) (poorly formatted)
- [Common Halal and non-halal Fish](http://www.islamic-laws.com/fish.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The Sunni schools do not prohibit fish without scales, though our Shia brothers do prohibit it.